# In Tensorflow 2.6, tf.keras.backend.gradients() return None

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to customize a loss functionm, But when I run the following code:

```
pressure_grad_x = tf.keras.backend.gradients(out2, cur_x_input)[0]
pressure_grad_y = tf.keras.backend.gradients(out2, cur_y_input)[0]
pressure_grad_z = tf.keras.backend.gradients(out2, cur_z_input)[0]
pressure_grad = tf.convert_to_tensor([pressure_grad_x, pressure_grad_y, pressure_grad_z])
```

An error will be reported(The above code is in the custom function.)：

```
<ipython-input-42-23232050871c>:34 call  *
    pressure_grad = tf.convert_to_tensor([pressure_grad_x, pressure_grad_y, pressure_grad_z])
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper  **
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:1431 convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch
    value, dtype=dtype, dtype_hint=dtype_hint, name=name)
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:1441 convert_to_tensor_v2
    as_ref=False)
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py:163 wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:1566 convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:346 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:272 constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:290 _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py:553 make_tensor_proto
    "supported type." % (type(values), values))

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, None, None]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

When I tried to solve it, I found that the value of pressure_grad_x (or pressure_grad_y, pressure_grad_z) is None.

The model i used is LSTM model and take the custom loss function as the last layer of the model.

out2 is the outputs of LSTM model. cur_x_input, cur_y_input, cur_z_input is the inputs of LSTM model.The version of Tensorflow is 2.6.0.

I have no way to solve this problem. I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need check you input shape, I feel, your given input is NONE.

Solved via using tf.shape

Comment: Thank you for your reply very much! The shape of out2 is (None, 4), the shape of cur_x_input( cur_y_input, cur_z_input ) is (None,4,1). Is there any problem? Thanks again！